# make or makes in this context?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Their love of (something) and (something) make/makes (I forget what was here). (sorry i forgot the blanks it was on an sat test)

Comment: The subject *love* is singular. Thus the verb should be *makes*.

Answer (score 1):

**The verb should be makes,** this is determined by their love of being singular.